# Looking for function replacement for Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant()

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to convert a COM VARIANT to an object by using GetObjectForNativeVariant(IntPtr) but this API is now obsolete. UWP returned exception when I run that API.
Exception Message: Marshalling between VARIANT and System.Object is not supported

I copied data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a byte array and convert to string (which is the object I want to return back with the API) but it does not give me my expected result.

```
GCHandle PropHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned);
return Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant(PropHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
```

Comment: They are not kidding about it, they eliminated all support for COM Automation in UWP.  The CLR enforces it by throwing a hard exception, not just through the Marshal backdoor.  No way to bypass it, no alternative.  Which does beg the question where that variant came from, given that there is no remaining api that you can use to create one.  You'd better run the WACK tool to ensure you are not using legacy code that will never pass certification.

Comment: Thank @Hans, so it is impossible to access COM objects from a Universal Windows app.

Comment: Not what that meant.  COM Automation is a specific subset of COM, with types like IDispatch, VARIANT, BSTR, SAFEARRAY.

Comment: which type you are  trying to marshal. If you are trying to marshal a winRT type to a winRT type, that won’t be a problem. But if he is trying to convert  a .net type to a winRT type. That will be a problem. Could share more detail?